# .net core console method call

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, console-application

I am trying to invoke a method from the Main() method of a .net core console application that should display two properties from an external api but the console is only displaying Hello World and no other result data, I also want the console to stay put and not disappear off the screen. All help pointers are most welcome and thank you in advance!

UserItem.cs -

```
public class UserItem
{
    public UserItem(string name, string url)
    {
        Name = name;
        Url = url;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs -

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        GetUser();            
    }
    // retrieve all.
    public static async void GetUser()
    {
        //baseUrl
        string baseUrl = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
        try
        {
            // HttpClient implements a IDisposable interface.
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //initiate Get Request (await will execute the using statement in order).
                using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl))
                {
                    //get content from response, then convert it to a c# object.
                    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                    {
                        //assign content to data variable by converting into a string using await.
                        var data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //If the data is not null log convert the data using newtonsoft JObject Parse class method.
                        if (content != null)
                        {
                            //log data object in the console
                            Console.WriteLine("data------------{0}", JObject.Parse(data)["results"]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("NO Data----------");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Hit------------");
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `async void` is fire and forget, your main application will continue to execute, return from `Main` and terminate, most likely before your async tasks completes. Instead, use `async Task` for your method, and await it in `Main` (hint, you can make Main be `async Task` as well if you're using a recent compiler)

Comment: As for pausing the app before it terminates, put a `Console.ReadLine();` towards the end of `Main(...)`. Once you've done that, post the output here.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: You should post that as an answer. Always await async stuff, unless you know exactly why you are not and understand fully the implications of not awaiting (i.e. you're making an informed decision not to await for a very specific purpose).

Comment: I couldn't get async Task to work as the method call in the Main() wasnt working i.e await GetUser(); but Console.ReadLine(); in the Main () shows me the output so thats a start, many thanks!

Comment: You would need to do `static async Task Main()` (I removed the args parameter as you don't seem to be using it but feel free to add it back if you need it), then you can await `GetUser` (after making GetUser return a Task)

Comment: _While it is ok here_, when moving to production ready code that's executed in a service, `using(HttpClient)` is actually an anti-pattern. Just to keep in mind for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            //Waits the API response
            GetUser().Wait();

            //Waits until a key is pressed.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        // retrieve all.
        public static async Task GetUser()
        {
           //...
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since the question is about .NET Core, the OP can use C# 7 which adds async support for Main